# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles'. Login exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity-2

In an app am working on, I added some test accounts together with appropriate roles in my 'DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges' migration class. Now when I try to login for the first time using

```
var result = await SignInManager
                .PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, true);
```

Asp.net identity throws the following exception

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AspNetUserRoles'. The duplicate key value is (4, 1).The statement has been terminated.


   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\1de24adb938b932d\StackExchange.Profiling\Data\ProfiledDbCommand.cs:line 233
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Any thoughts on what might be causing the exception will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you're using AddOrUpdate in your seed method, or set to always drop the database depending on what dev stage you're in.

Comment: @EddiePaz the exception occurs not in my seed method, but after the application has been seeded and is started, that is when i want to login into the application.

Comment: Somewhere in your code you must be trying to add the same role to a user. Try clearing the tables and use SQL profiler or log the context to see where it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the  **`drop TABLE [dbo].[TableName]`**.

Make sure you're using AddOrUpdate in your seed method, or set to always drop the database depending on what development stage you're in

you are missing below

just drop TABLE [dbo].[TableName]